# Finding diffeomorphism given vector fields

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, vector-fields, flow

Given a vector field how do you find the associated diffeomorphisms? Say I am given a vector field in Minkowski space

$$\xi = x \frac{\partial}{\partial t} + t \frac{\partial}{\partial x}.$$

How do I find the associated diffeomorphism, if one exist? I know in this example the Lorentz boost in the x-direction is the diffeomorphism, but I am having trouble understanding how to arrive at that answer. Additionally, how do you tell when they might not have an associated diffeomorphism? I am lead to believe that this vector field cannot have a diffeomorphism translating points forward

$$ \xi = e^{x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, actually you are looking for a **one-parameter group of diffeomorphisms** (or isometries if referring to the boost vector field). This group is obtained by solving the differential equation $$\frac{dx}{ds}= X(x(s))\tag{1}$$
with a generic initial condition $z$ at $s=0$ in the manifold $M$ (Minkowski spacetime in your example).
 $X$ is your vector field on $M$. The solutions have the form $$M \times \mathbb R \ni (z,s) \mapsto \phi_s(z)$$
where $z$ is the initial condition, that is the point $x(0)= \phi_0(x) =z$ and the proper solution of (1) with that initial condition, $z$, is $x_s= \phi_s(z)$.
It turns out that 
$$\phi_0 = id\:, \quad \phi_s \circ \phi_r = \phi_{s+r}\:,\quad \phi_{-s}= (\phi_s)^{-1}\:.$$
Each $\phi_s : M \to M$ is a diffeomorphism. The **one-parameter group of diffeomorphisms** associated to $X$ is the family of diffeomorphisms $\{\phi_t\}_{t \in \mathbb R}$.

Generally speaking, the group is only local, i.e., not defined for all values of $s$ (the $s$-domain depends on $z$), but I will not discuss this point in this elementary presentation.

In the concrete case of the boost vector field, you have to solve the system
$$\frac{dt}{ds}= x(s)\:,\quad \frac{dx}{ds}= t(s)$$
This way you find that $\phi_s((t,x))= (t(s),x(s))$ with
$$t(s) = x\sinh(s)+ t\cosh(s)\:, \quad  x(s) = x\cosh(s)+ t\sinh(s)\:.$$
Ragarding your last question about the exponential vector field, you can solve it yourself now.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations, that helped clear a lot of things. I can now see that for the second question, $x(s) = log(1/(s-exp(-x))$, and then this will diverge for some finite $s>0$. Is there another way to determine when vector fields are ill-behaved in this sense without first doing a calculation?

Comment: Actually I do not know. I suspect that such methods must exist. There are methods to check if the local group is global, which means that each solution with each initial condition is *complete*, i.e. the parameter $s$ ranges in the whole real axis. This is the case, for instance, if  $M$ is compact (I assume that $X$ is at least continuous). But I do not know sufficient conditions for incompleteness of the orbits. I am not an expert on this topic.

Comment: @NoviceC (and Valter) I know of some partial result: Vector fields in $\Bbb R^n$ with at most linear growth are complete (i.e. their flows are defined for all times). Here, "at most linear growth" means that for $\lvert x \rvert$ sufficiently large, $\lvert X(x)\rvert \leq C \lvert x \rvert$ for some constant $C$. Generically, things with larger (e.g. quadratic growth) will lead to finite "end time", but I have no theorem to support that assertion.